# Git: How to reset your current branch?

Tags: git, github

I messed up my current branch and have a few unpushed commits.

I've done a git rebase too and it is very messy now.

So I want to start fresh with the branch that is online, how do I go about doing this?

Also, as I mentioned I have unpushed commits on my local so I want them to go as well - will restarting delete all my unpushed commits?

Thank you!

Comment: The "branch that is online" does not include non-pushed commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your local branch with git branch -D <branch_name> and then pull it again from your origin

Comment: Or `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>`